# CachedRowSetImpl getString based on column label throws "Invalid column name"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

When I execute following code all is good:

```
ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT r.UID AS R FROM r").executeQuery();
System.out.println(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getString("R"));
```

the result is:

```
R
23
```

But when I execute following code:

```
ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT r.UID AS R FROM r").executeQuery();
CachedRowSetImpl rslt = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rslt.populate(rs);
System.out.println(rslt.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
rslt.next();
System.out.println(rslt.getString("R"));
```

the result is:

```
R
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

Why does it throw an exception here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the reference implementation of `CachedRowSet` (`com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`) contains a bug: When you retrieve a column by name, it uses the `columnName`, and **not** the `columnLabel`, therefor going against the rest of the JDBC specification which uses the `columnLabel` to retrieve values. This bug makes it impossible to retrieve values from the rowset by the `columnLabel`.

The bug at Oracle is https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7046875, but (surprise, surprise) they have made it unavailable for public viewing.

There are two potential workaround. One is to check if your driver provides a property to also have the `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(..)` method return the `columnLabel` value, the second workaround would be to create a subclass of `CachedRowSetImpl` (which unfortunately requires a lot of overriding methods).

The version below is copied from this message: [Re: Regression from 2.1.6](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-java/2012/7/10715.html)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Ref;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl;

import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;

public class FixedCachedRowSetImpl extends CachedRowSetImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9067504047398250113L;
    private RowSetMetaDataImpl RowSetMD;

    public FixedCachedRowSetImpl() throws SQLException {
        super();
    }

    public FixedCachedRowSetImpl(Hashtable env) throws SQLException {
        super(env);
    }

    private int getColIdxByName(String name) throws SQLException {
        RowSetMD = (RowSetMetaDataImpl) this.getMetaData();
        int cols = RowSetMD.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= cols; ++i) {
            String colName = RowSetMD.getColumnLabel(i);
            if (colName != null) if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(colName))
                return (i);
            else
                continue;
        }
        throw new SQLException(resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.invalcolnm").toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> toCollection(String column) throws SQLException {
        return toCollection(getColIdxByName(column));
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getString(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBoolean(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public byte getByte(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getByte(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public short getShort(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getShort(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getInt(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getLong(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getFloat(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public double getDouble(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getDouble(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(String columnName, int scale) throws SQLException {
        return getBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName), scale);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBytes(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date getDate(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getDate(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Time getTime(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getTime(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getAsciiStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getAsciiStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));

    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getUnicodeStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getUnicodeStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getBinaryStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBinaryStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getObject(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public int findColumn(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getColIdxByName(columnName);
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.Reader getCharacterStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getCharacterStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean columnUpdated(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return columnUpdated(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateNull(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        updateNull(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBoolean(String columnName, boolean x) throws SQLException {
        updateBoolean(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateByte(String columnName, byte x) throws SQLException {
        updateByte(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateShort(String columnName, short x) throws SQLException {
        updateShort(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateInt(String columnName, int x) throws SQLException {
        updateInt(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLong(String columnName, long x) throws SQLException {
        updateLong(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFloat(String columnName, float x) throws SQLException {
        updateFloat(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDouble(String columnName, double x) throws SQLException {
        updateDouble(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBigDecimal(String columnName, BigDecimal x) throws SQLException {
        updateBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateString(String columnName, String x) throws SQLException {
        updateString(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBytes(String columnName, byte x[]) throws SQLException {
        updateBytes(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDate(String columnName, java.sql.Date x) throws SQLException {
        updateDate(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTime(String columnName, java.sql.Time x) throws SQLException {
        updateTime(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTimestamp(String columnName, java.sql.Timestamp x) throws SQLException {
        updateTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAsciiStream(String columnName, java.io.InputStream x, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateAsciiStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBinaryStream(String columnName, java.io.InputStream x, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateBinaryStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCharacterStream(String columnName, java.io.Reader reader, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateCharacterStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), reader, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObject(String columnName, Object x, int scale) throws SQLException {
        updateObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, scale);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObject(String columnName, Object x) throws SQLException {
        updateObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject(String columnName, java.util.Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        return getObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), map);
    }

    @Override
    public Ref getRef(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getRef(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Blob getBlob(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getBlob(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Clob getClob(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getClob(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Array getArray(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getArray(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date getDate(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getDate(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Time getTime(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getTime(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateRef(String columnName, java.sql.Ref ref) throws SQLException {
        updateRef(getColIdxByName(columnName), ref);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateClob(String columnName, Clob c) throws SQLException {
        updateClob(getColIdxByName(columnName), c);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBlob(String columnName, Blob b) throws SQLException {
        updateBlob(getColIdxByName(columnName), b);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateArray(String columnName, Array a) throws SQLException {
        updateArray(getColIdxByName(columnName), a);
    }

    @Override
    public java.net.URL getURL(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getURL(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }
}
```

You could also look at [`org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/rowset/ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.html), which also says:

> Note: Since JDBC 4.0, it has been clarified that any methods using a String to identify the column should be using the column label. The column label is assigned using the ALIAS keyword in the SQL query string. When the query doesn't use an ALIAS, the default label is the column name. Most JDBC ResultSet implementations follow this new pattern but there are exceptions such as the com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl class which only uses the column name, ignoring any column labels. As of Spring 3.0.5, `ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet` will translate column labels to the correct column index to provide better support for the `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` which is the default implementation used by `JdbcTemplate` when working with RowSets.

Comment: In Netbeans I get InvalidResultSetAccessException cannot be converted to throwable when trying to create new ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet(crs), where crs is a CachedRowSetIml. Both throws clause and try-catch fail. Could you suggest something?

Comment: As for the first variant - how do you do crs.populate(rs); if there is no populate method seen, inspite of it extends from CachedRowSetImpl?

Comment: @Zon `ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet` can - as far as I know - only wrap a normal `ResultSet`. You should use it instead of `CachedRowSetImpl`, not wrap a `CachedRowSetImpl` (that would also defeat the purpose of wrapping as it would already be too late). As to your second question: the method exists in the superclass, so you should be able to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner select:

```
ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM (SELECT r.UID AS R FROM r) AA").executeQuery();
CachedRowSetImpl rslt = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rslt.populate(rs);
System.out.println(rslt.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
rslt.next();
System.out.println(rslt.getString("R"));
```

Comment: This just gave me an error `Table '<database_name>.AA' doesn't exist`. My `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` worked fine though.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround seems to be to wrap your columns in a function or mathematical operation. Then you can use the alias in the `CachedRowSetImpl`.

If your SQL is this:

```
SELECT
  id AS student_id,
  cost - discount AS total_cost,
  first_name AS name
FROM
  students
```

You will be able to refer to `studentRow.getBigDecimal("total_cost")`, but `studentRow.getLong("student_id")` and `studentRow.getString("name")` will fail with an `SQLException` "Invalid column name".

But if your SQL was like this:

```
SELECT
  id + 0 AS student_id,
  cost - discount AS total_cost,
  CONCAT(first_name) AS name
FROM
  students
```

Then it works as you would expect.

I'm not sure what the performance penalty would be for this, but it will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

the latest JDK 1.7 already implement CachedRowSet and the label name bug has been fixed!

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;

ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT r.UID AS R FROM r").executeQuery();
RowSetFactory rowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet crs = rowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
crs.populate(rs);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Java 7 - Still column names istead of column labels.

Answer (score -1):

Here my improved version of getColIdxByName to support MySQL 5.x names like "tbl.column":

```
private int getColIdxByName(String name) throws SQLException {
    RowSetMD = (RowSetMetaDataImpl) this.getMetaData();
    int cols = RowSetMD.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 1; i <= cols; ++i) {
        String colLabel = RowSetMD.getColumnLabel(i);
        String colName  = RowSetMD.getColumnName(i);
        if (colName != null) if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(colName) || name.equalsIgnoreCase(RowSetMD.getTableName(i) + "." + colName)) {               
            return (i);
        }
        else if (colLabel != null) if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(colLabel)) {
            return (i);
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    throw new SQLException(resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.invalcolnm").toString());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't colLabel compared to name have priority; in other words shouldn't "colLabel.equalsIgnoreCase(name)" be checked first?  The bug that's the subject of this thread is that colLabel is not checked first.