# JAVA MySQL illogical error

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error, not-exists

Query:

```sql
SELECT 
t1.id, atsakingo_id, darbuotojo_id, darbu_id, medz_id, t1.data, dvardas, dpavarde,
avardas, apavarde, klientas_id, klientas, adresas, darbas, medziaga, medz_kiekis, 
t1.komentaras, val_uzmok, t1.busena, t1.atl_data, t1.aktai 
FROM irasai t1 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.id) as darbuotojo_id, irasai_darb_id.iraso_id, GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.vardas) as dvardas, GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.pavarde) as dpavarde 
     FROM irasai_darb_id 
     LEFT JOIN darbuotojai ON irasai_darb_id.darb_id = darbuotojai.id 
     GROUP BY iraso_id) 
AS t2 ON t2.iraso_id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.id) as atsakingo_id, irasai_ats_id.iraso_id, GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.vardas) as avardas, GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.pavarde) as apavarde, GROUP_CONCAT(darbuotojai.uzmok) as val_uzmok 
     FROM irasai_ats_id 
     LEFT JOIN darbuotojai ON irasai_ats_id.ats_id = darbuotojai.id 
     GROUP BY iraso_id) 
AS t3 ON t3.iraso_id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(darbai.id) as darbu_id, irasai_darbai_id.iraso_id, GROUP_CONCAT(darbai.darbas) as darbas 
     FROM irasai_darbai_id 
     LEFT JOIN darbai ON irasai_darbai_id.darbo_id = darbai.id 
     GROUP BY iraso_id) 
AS t4 ON t4.iraso_id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(medziagos.id) as medz_id, irasai_medziagos_id.iraso_id, GROUP_CONCAT(medziagos.medziaga) as medziaga, GROUP_CONCAT(irasai_medziagos_id.kiekis) as medz_kiekis 
     FROM irasai_medziagos_id 
     LEFT JOIN medziagos ON irasai_medziagos_id.medziagos_id = medziagos.id 
     GROUP BY iraso_id) 
AS t5 ON t5.iraso_id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id as klientas_id, klientas as klientas, adresas as adresas 
     FROM klientai) 
AS t6 ON t6.klientas_id = t1.kliento_id
```

How it is executing (Query is in String sql):

```
rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
```

Error goes for:

```
CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
crs.populate(rs); //THIS LINE
```

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'darbai.t6' doesn't exist

Query runs okay from PhpMyAdmin, running it from JAVA program getting this illogical/impossible error.

SOLUTION: [cachedrowsetimpl getString based on column label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184709/cachedrowsetimpl-getstring-based-on-column-label)

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the query to identify which part is causing the problem? Obviously it has something to do with t4-section, but what happens if you remove other sections.

Comment: If I remove t6, no error, if I remove t4 or leave only t4 and t6, same error. I don't understand from where it gets darbai table then t4 is removed??? First I was using simle LEFT JOIN for t6 (no select, just join), and it was working, but I need t6 table id column, and I can't use AS in first select because of CachedRowSetImpl(can't get columns by name if them is with AS)

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Must be a bug in the JDBC driver or in CachedRowSetImpl.